# Python sqlite fetchmany and fetchall return ordered results

Tags: python, sqlite, fetchall

I've noticed that the Python sqlite fetchall() and fetchmany() statements return results in sorted key order rather than the original key order. For example, consider:

```
list_indexes = [9, 5, 2, 8, 3, 7]

indexsize = len(list_indexes)
cursor.arraysize = indexsize

cursor.execute("select index, details from this_table where index in (%s)" % ','.join('?' * len(list_indexes)), list_indexes)
rows = cursor.fetchmany(indexsize)
```

The returned order of rows is by sorted key order [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9].

Have I missed something or is this the default behavior?  If so, is there a workaround apart from the obvious one to re-sort rows by argument index?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal behaviour. Unless you specify `ORDER BY` in your query, order of rows in result is undefined. If you have some field that can be used for sorting (date, for example), you should use it.

You can use temporary table to do that you want:

```
; prepare test table
CREATE TABLE this_table (`index` INTEGER, record_details TEXT);
INSERT INTO this_table VALUES (1, 'a1');
INSERT INTO this_table VALUES (2, 'a2');
; ...
INSERT INTO this_table VALUES (10, 'a10');

; do the query
CREATE TEMP TABLE good_indexes(number INTEGER, i integer);
INSERT INTO good_indexes(number, i) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO good_indexes(number, i) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO good_indexes(number, i) VALUES (3, 6);

SELECT record_details FROM this_table, good_indexes 
WHERE good_indexes.i = this_table.`index` ORDER BY good_indexes.number;
; result: a4, a2, a6

DROP TABLE good_indexes;
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. wrt to a workaround, it is easier to re-sort the rows using the argument index.